# Trying to highlight a table row after input is checked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Asking this question because while it has been solved with JQuery on here, I didn't see any JavaScript solutions for it.

I have a simple table with a structure like so:

```

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

```

For some reason, my javascript function to highlight the entire row is not working:

```

```
var rowElement = document.querySelector('tr');
rowElement.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
    var clickedElement = e.target; // this is checking what was the target element that is being clicked on, and that could be the checkbox inside the row
    var clickedElementName = clickedElement.tagName.toLowerCase(); // we need to get the name to see if the element was an input element, using toLowerCase because those names are often uppercase
    if ( clickedElementName === 'input' && clickedElementName.checked ) {
          // if the clicked element is an input element, and is checked, meaning it's a checkbox, do the following:
         this.style.color = "blue"; // 'this' is the element that we are listening on, that is, the rowElement
    }
})
```

```

Comment: `clickedElementName.checked` should be `clickedElement.checked`

Comment: Haha, woops, thank you @brunjick

Answer (score 0):

please use this code:

```js
var rowElement = document.querySelector('tr');
rowElement.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
    var clickedElement = e.target; // this is checking what was the target element that is being clicked on, and that could be the checkbox inside the row
    var clickedElementName = clickedElement.tagName.toLowerCase(); // we need to get the name to see if the element was an input element, using toLowerCase because those names are often uppercase
    if ( clickedElementName === 'input' && clickedElement.checked ) {
          // if the clicked element is an input element, and is checked, meaning it's a checkbox, do the following: 
         clickedElement.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "blue"; // 'this' is the element that we are listening on, that is, the rowElement
    }else{
        clickedElement.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = "";
    }
})
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"/></td><td>cell</td></tr>
</table>
```